# "Miderton" DPDT relay 8 pin

Tags: relay, pins, dpdt

[image]

I am trying to get a small 1.5V display motor to turn 1st one direction and then the opposite. I understood that a "miderton" DTDP relay 8 pin would do this. The coil relay part is 12V. The relay is plugged into a base. I can get the motor to turn in one direction however when I activate the 12V coil it stops the motor but when the 12V coil is un-activated the motor continues in the same direction. I wired it according to YouTube videos for 8 pin relays.

Also the base has a small flat orange spring loaded tab on the bottom but I do not what this is for or how to use it.
Any help would be appreciated.

**SPECIFICATIONS**
12V DC Coil Power Relay LY2NJ DPDT 8 Pin HH62P JQX-13F With Socket Base

Model: LY2NJ (8 pins)

- Coil voltage: DC12V
- Coil Power: DC (W): ≤0.9AC (VA): ≤1.2
- Contact Structure: 8 pins 2 normally open 2 normally closed
- Contact capacity: 10A 250VAC
- Pull-in voltage: ≤80% (V)
- Release voltage: DC: ≥10% (V), AC: ≥30%
- Contact resistance: ≤50 (mΩ)
- Insulation resistance: ≤100 (mΩ)
- Dimensions: 27.5 × 21 × 35.3mm
- Terminals form: Socket
- Action time: 20ms or less
- Reset Time: 20ms or less
- Operating frequency:

  - Mechanical 18,000 cycles / hour
  - Electrical 18,000 times / hour

[image: underside of base - spring loaded orange tab]

[![wired as per youtube vid][1][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EMjj.png)

My knowledge of of all of this and circuits is low. Are you saying as per your image LY2(2)
that pin 1 & 3 should be wired together and pin 3 & 4 should be wired together instead of my pin 4 & 5 and pin 3 & 6 together?

Comment: You  need to show us what you've done. [Edit your question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/450327/edit) and use the built-in schematic editor.

Comment: Please add a schematic diagram showing how you wired it, and provide a link to a datasheet for the relay.  We don't know what connections the YouTube videos you saw showed.

Comment: The orange thing is used to latch the relay socket onto a DIN rail - nothing to do with the relay contacts or operation. We still need datasheets for the relay and socket to detmine the required wiring.

Comment: If you are asking a question about my answer then please place this in a comment below my answer.

Comment: My knowledge of of all of this and circuits is low. Are you saying as per your image LY2(2) that pin 1 & 3 should be wired together and pin 3 & 4 should be wired together instead of my pin 4 & 5 and pin 3 & 6 together? –

Comment: I added the specs.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBWsCr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Either layout above will work for motor reversing control.*

[image]

*Figure 2. LY2 pintout from [datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2005878.pdf?_ga=2.16295414.1969166596.1564386021-1133008779.1543418644) page 7.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feVgKq.png)</sup>

*Figure 3. Addition of snubber diodes will reduce contact arcing and prolong relay life.*

Comment: My knowledge of of all of this and circuits is low. Are you saying as per your image LY2(2) that pin 1 & 3 should be wired together and pin 3 & 4 should be wired together instead of my pin 4 & 5 and pin 3 & 6 together?